# Creating a class derived from CTabCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, derived-class, ctabctrl

I am following a tutorial to use CTabCtrl.  The tutorial is asking me to create a class that is derived from CTabCtrl.  I am unsure if I am doing this correctly.  This is the header for my custom class.

```
#pragma once


// CTabbyControl

class CTabbyControl : public CTabCtrl
{
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTabbyControl)

public:
CTabbyControl();
virtual ~CTabbyControl();

protected:
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and am following [this tutorial](http://simplesamples.info/MFC/CTabCtrl.html).
My problem is that the tutorial asks me to create a CTabbyControl variable in the class wizard.  I only have the option to use CTabCtrl.  This brings me to think that I am deriving incorrectly. I have never derived a class.  Is the way I am doing it a correct method of deriving?

```
http://simplesamples.info/MFC/CTabCtrl.html
```

Comment: Looks good so far. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I updated my question to better explain myself, thank you. @Mark Ransom

Comment: Create the instance of your control using `CTabCtrl` and then find/replace `CTabCtrl` with `CTabbyCtrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether you have included the Header file (TabbyControl.h) in the class you try to create the object of TabbyControl.